# Why there are redefinition errors when inheritance from a base template class and put both class file in separate header files?

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance

My base template class is in Base.h:

```
#include <iostream>
using  std::cout;
using std::endl;


#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

template<typename T>
class Base
{
    public:
        Base();
        Base(T a0, T b0);
        void display();
    private:
        T a,b;
        T sum();
};

#endif // BASE_H

template<typename T>
Base<T>::Base():a(0),b(0){}

template<typename T>
Base<T>::Base(T a0, T b0):a(a0),b(b0){}

template<typename T>
T Base<T>::sum()
{
    return a+b;
}

template<typename T>
void Base<T>::display()
{
    cout<<"The sum is: "<<sum()<<endl;
}
```

And my Derived.h file is:

```
#ifndef DERIVED_H
#define DERIVED_H

#include <Base.h>

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
    public:
        Derived(){}
        Derived(T a0, T b0);
        void display1();
};

#endif // DERIVED_H

template<typename T>
Derived<T>::Derived(T a0, T b0):Base<T>(a0,b0) {}

template<T>
void Derived<T>::display1()
{

    this->display();
}
```

I do know implementation of template class should not be in .cpp file, but why there is undefined error when I put the separate header files in different .h file?

The error is showed as follows (with code::blocks):

```
 ***include\Base.h|24|error: redefinition of 'Base<T>::Base()'|
 include\Base.h|24|error: 'Base<T>::Base()' previously declared here|***
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the code. Do you have include guards?

Comment: I corrected my question just now because this is my first time to ask question on this site, thank you for your answer.

Comment: No, when I delete the Derived.h file, the Base class can functioning well.

Comment: Replace include guards with `#pragma once`, if error disappears, than your include guards are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues. First, your `#include` guards are wrong. You are only guarding the class declaration:

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

template<typename T>
class Base
{
    ...
};

#endif // BASE_H

... definitions of Base<T> ...
```

If `Base.h` is `#include`d twice, you'll only get one class declaration (good) but then you'll get multiple definitions of all the member functions (bad).

The `#include` guards should guard the *entire* file. Move the `#ifndef` to the first line and the `#endif` to the last line.

Second issue, if you provide your member function definitions in the header but external to the class declaration, you have to mark the function as `inline` (this can be done either in the declaration or the definition, but personally I prefer the declaration). That is:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
   ...
   inline Base();
   inline void display();
   inline T sum();
};

// definitions...
```

Comment: I thought at first that the rest of the code was in a different file with the way the include guards are.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is solved with your great answer!